# Compact manifold with smooth structure

Tags: manifolds, riemann-surfaces

Is the following surface smooth and compact, when all its partial derivatives are continuous?

How to tell about self-intersections without visualization?

$x=\cos(a) + \cos(a + b) + \cos(a + b + c),$

$y=  \sin(a) + \sin(a + b) + \cos(a + b + c)$

$z=  \sin(a) + \cos(a + b) + \sin(a + b + c) $

inside the interval $ (a, -\pi, \pi), (b, -\pi, \pi)$

For Mathematica visualization:

Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[a] + Cos[a + b] + Cos[a + b + c], 
   Sin[a] + Sin[a + b] + Cos[a + b + c], 
   Sin[a] + Cos[a + b] + Sin[a + b + c]}, {a, -Pi, Pi}, {b, -Pi, Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Yellow}, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False], {c, -Pi/2, 
  Pi/2, Pi/24}]

Comment: It looks like for $c=0$ it collapses into a planar surface and this is not smooth at its boundary.

Comment: @ioannis galidakis My question is: What mathematical procedure without seeing its computer image detects non-smoothness at c=0?

Comment: Obviously you cannot tell without looking at the graph first. But since from the graph I see that the collapse happens at $c=0$, it suffices to look at a discontinuity around there. So, evaluate (for $\epsilon\to 0$): $x(0,0,c-\epsilon)$ and $y(0,0,c+\epsilon)$ and compare the two values with $z(0,0,c)$. I get: $2.99995$, $0.9999500004$, $1$. And there you have it.

Comment: @ioannisgalidakis You mean (like there is a test for series convergence), there is no way to test smoothness and compactness ? always a *post facto* analysis?

Comment: The test for smoothness and compactness is simple: You look at where the manifold $M(x,y,z)$ is singular. If you find ONE singular point, you are done, since a singularity at $(x,y,z)$ implies non-smoothness of $M$. In this case you just take advantage of the visual queue, so you test at the first suspcicious point from the queue, which is $(0,0,0)$. $M$ is singular there, so you are done.

Comment: @ioannisgalidakis. Thanks, I see the point. It is quite simple.